# Logistic regression with robust clustered standard errors in R

Tags: r, regression, stata

A newbie question: does anyone know how to run a logistic regression with clustered standard errors in R? In Stata it's just `logit Y X1 X2 X3, vce(cluster Z)`, but unfortunately I haven't figured out how to do the same analysis in R. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the `vcovHC()` function in the `sandwich` package might also be useful (not sure if it applies to logistic regression estimates)

Comment: if you're migrating from Stata you might find the package called ``plm`` useful. Also, there is the package called ``pcse`` for implementing panel corrected standard errors by manipulating the variance covariance matrix after estimation

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies, Ben and Hubert. I will also test the packages you have suggested and see if they work with logistic estimates. Thanks again!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to look at the `rms` (regression modelling strategies) package.  So, `lrm` is logistic regression model, and if `fit` is the name of your output, you'd have something like this:

```
fit=lrm(disease ~ age + study + rcs(bmi,3), x=T, y=T, data=dataf)

fit

robcov(fit, cluster=dataf$id)

bootcov(fit,cluster=dataf$id)
```

You have to specify `x=T`, `y=T` in the model statement.  `rcs` indicates restricted cubic splines with 3 knots.

Comment: Thank you very much! It has worked wonders! I will read rms's manual more closely and see if there is a way of clustering the coefficients by country and also by year. Once again, thank you!

Comment: This answer is already very good but it could be improved if it was fully replicable. I have not idea where the variables come from, what the output is, and why `rcs(bmi,3)` is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative would be to use the `sandwich` and `lmtest` package as follows. Suppose that `z` is a column with the cluster indicators in your dataset `dat`. Then

```r
# load libraries
library("sandwich")
library("lmtest")

# fit the logistic regression
fit = glm(y ~ x, data = dat, family = binomial)

# get results with clustered standard errors (of type HC0)
coeftest(fit, vcov. = vcovCL(fit, cluster = dat$z, type = "HC0"))
```

will do the job.

Comment: Fun fact on that comment: The functions in  ```miceadds``` actually refer to the sandwich package :)

Answer (score 5):

I have been banging my head against this problem for the past two days; I magically found what appears to be a new package which seems destined for great things--for example, I am also running in my analysis some cluster-robust Tobit models, and this package has that functionality built in as well. Not to mention the syntax is *much* cleaner than in all the other solutions I've seen (we're talking near-Stata levels of clean).

So for your toy example, I'd run:

```
library(Zelig)
logit<-zelig(Y~X1+X2+X3,data=data,model="logit",robust=T,cluster="Z")
```

Et voilà!

Comment: Wow, that does appear to "just work" in ways that my R code never seems to. Is this new functionality? If not, why has Zelig not been the canonical way to solve this in R?

Comment: Don't know, but I hope it becomes so. [The project](http://zeligproject.org) certainly seems ambitious! The [Google group]( https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/zelig-statistical-software) doesn't seem so active though, so not sure how quick progress is.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the command doesn't work in the latest version of `Zelig` (on CRAN). I've just run a few models with and without the `cluster` argument and the standard errors are exactly the same. I believe it's been like that since version 4.0, the last time I used the package.

Comment: yes, indeed they've dropped that functionality for now. check their google group (go to the community section of their website)--they're in the middle of restructuring the whole project; one of the developers said in reply to a post of mine that they're working on bringing back cluster/robust functionality

Comment: About three years later, cluster functionality is not back: `Error in glm.control(cluster = "group") :   unused argument (cluster = "group")`.

Comment: Any update on whether this now includes the cluster functionality?

Answer (score 5):

There is a command `glm.cluster` in the R package `miceadds` which seems to give the same results for logistic regression as Stata does with the option `vce(cluster)`.  See the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/miceadds/versions/3.5-14/topics/lm.cluster).

In one of the examples on this page, the commands

```
mod2 <- miceadds::glm.cluster(data=dat, formula=highmath ~ hisei + female,
                              cluster="idschool", family="binomial")
summary(mod2)
```

give the same robust standard errors as the Stata command

```
logit highmath hisei female, vce(cluster idschool)
```

e.g. a standard error of 0.004038 for the variable `hisei`.